# Stuck on boot after updating to 18.10

Tags: boot, nvidia, 18.10

I updated my 18.04 to 18.10 and after rebooting it gets stuck on the boot screen. What can I do to fix this? In case it helps, I have an Nvidia card...

[image]

Comment: You could try and turn off the splash screen in order to see boot messages: Upon power-up, when the grub menu appears, press **E** to edit the boot entry for your current kernel, and delete the `splash` from the line starting with `linux`. This deactivates that splash screen and you see all the error messages during the boot process.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same situation.

Running on an older Pentium 2 box, and I was very happy with the performance on Ubuntu 18.04 but I moved forward to Ubuntu 18.10.

That worked fine until they sent me the first kernel upgrade (4.18.0.10 to 4.18.0.14).

The 4.18.0.14 would not budge from the boot screen, so I went back to Ubuntu 18.04 which works like a charm.